# Two self reference field in same db model mongoengine

Tags: python, models, mongoengine

I have a db models like following:

```
class Image(mongoengine.Document):

    project = mongoengine.ReferenceField('Project', required=True, 
                                 reverse_delete_rule=mongoengine.CASCADE)
    next = mongoengine.ReferenceField('self', required=False)
    prev = mongoengine.ReferenceField('self', required=False)

    name = mongoengine.StringField(unique_with='project', required=True)
    created_on = mongoengine.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
```

There are two fields referring back to same model.

Just to test the validity I removed one of them and then tried to save an Image object, it worked, but when both next and prev are in the dbmodel, in this case while saving an image object I am getting a error that:

```
ValidationError: None is not a valid ObjectId.
```

How to resolve this issue?
Does mongoengine does not support to have two self referring dbfields?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the error.

> next

is an inbuilt function, which should not be kept as a dbfield.

replacing it with any other variable which is not an inbuilt property will work.